# How is $\exists$ formulated in a FOL proof system?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

$\exists x \phi(x)$ in mathematics  means there is something $c$, s.t. $\phi(c)$ holds.
What is the formulation of that same idea as a inference rule, an axiom,  or something else in a proof system in FOL?

Particularly what is the elimination rule for $\exists$? (It is not correct that if $\Phi \vdash \exists x \phi$, there exists a term $t$ so  $\Phi \vdash \phi[t/x]$.)

What is the similar one for $\forall$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Natural Deduction](https://iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H7) proof system we have a pair of inference rules for the existential (as well as the universal) quantifier:

> $(\exists \text I) \ \varphi [x/a] \vdash \exists x \varphi$

> $(\exists \text E) \ \text { if } \Gamma \vdash \exists x \varphi \text { and } \Delta, \varphi [x/a] \vdash \psi, \text { then } \Gamma, \Delta \vdash \psi$.

In an Hilbert-style proof system we have at least one axiom for it, unless it is defined in terms of the universal one.

See e.g. J. Shoenfield, [Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=Vl1ZDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA21) for the axiom

> $A[x/a] \to \exists x A$

and the rule:

> $\dfrac {A \to B}{\exists x A \to B}$, provided that $x$ is not free in $B$.

In [Enderton's system (see page 78)](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA78) the existential quantifier is an abbreviation: $∃x α$ abbreviates $(¬∀x(¬α))$.

Comment: can you list the rules or axioms? Are they for both introduction and elimination?

Comment: How about elimination?

Comment: Thanks. in https://iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H7, What does the introduction rule $(\forall I)$ for $\forall$  say? If $\Gamma \vdash \phi[x/a]$, then $\Gamma \vdash \forall x \phi$. Does it say that if there is a term $a$ so that $\Gamma \vdash \phi[x/a]$, then $\Gamma \vdash \forall x \phi$? That is not true though

Comment: @Mary - you have forgotten the proviso: provided that $a$ is not free in $\Gamma$.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4061319/what-is-arbitrary-object-in-mathematics) as well as some posts regarding [UG](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3914609/universal-generalisation-forall-i) and [$\forall \text I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1845721/invalid-application-of-universal-introduction)

Comment: Do you mean $a$ must be free in $\Gamma$,  and $\phi$?

Comment: Why must $a$ be free (or not free) in Γ, and ϕ?

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to introduce $\exists$ in a FOL proof system.

I think the most common approach is that $\exists$ is defined via $\forall$:

$$\exists x \phi(x) \stackrel{\text{def}}\iff \lnot\forall x \lnot \phi(x).$$

And $\forall$ is introduced axiomatically before that.

Comment: Are there rules/axioms for both introduction and elimination?